# Add fonts into CSS

Tags: css, font-awesome, font-face

To add fontawsome fonts to my site, I added this to my CSS :

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwsome';
  src: url('./webagency_images/fonts/fontawsome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('./webagency_images/fonts/fontawsome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('./webagency_images/fonts/fontawsome-webfont.svg') format('svg');
  src: url('./webagency_images/fonts/fontawsome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('./webagency_images/fonts/FontAwsome.otf') format('otf');
}
```

My fonts are in webagency_images/fonts

Am I doing something wrong?
They don't displlay on the site...

Comment: Why not just reference the CDN in you header?

Comment: I would think `src: url('webagency_images/fonts/fontawsome-webfont.eot');` would do it.  Or use the CDN.

Comment: Seeing as you're integrating font-awesome into your project/website, I would refer to the getting started section of the documentation(https://fontawesome.com/get-started) . You do not need to declare these fonts as such in your CSS to utilize them, generally speaking FontAwesome is imported in the <head> of your website.

Answer (score 3):

If you decide to use the CDN directly, do the following and change the version number to the most current.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css' type='text/css' />
```

Or you can add the below at the very top of your CSS file:

```
@import url("https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css");
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct url should be:

```
src: url('../webagency_images/fonts/fontawsome-webfont.eot');
```